# Chrome Extension Background Page Show Popup Page

Tags: google-chrome, popup, background

I am making a Google Chrome extension and I would like to have my background page to cause the browser action's popup page to show after an event. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, when I say I want the popup page to show, I don't want it to show in a new tab. I want it to popup just as if you would have clicked the browser action icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot show/hide a browser action nor you can trigger a popup to open. If you need something to show, did you consider using HTML5 notifications?